# Cloning a directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I include a directive on my page as so:

```
<module ng-repeat="module in moduleGallery.modules" module-obj="module"></module>
```

where the directive is defined as:

```
angular.module('module-module', [])
.directive('module', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'modules/module/module.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'moduleCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'moduleCtrl',
        scope: {
            moduleObj: '='
        }
    };
});
```

Note that the module-obj attribute is variable. Now, I am finding myself needing to clone the generated directive so that I have 2 or 3 or ??? The controllers will be unique -- i.e. a click event on one clone, shouldn't affect all the clones. Also, ideally, the controller of the clone will instantiate to the same state as the source. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: More than half of the words in your code are `module`. just sayin.

Comment: _"clone the generated directive"_ Means what? Clone the element? That's what `ngRepeat` already does.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459 ...
this might help

Comment: @Daniel -- fully agree that this is confusing. It's a proof of concept -- non-production

Comment: @zeroflagL I posed this question abstractly, but ultimately, I am using this as part of a drag and drop angular functionality. I want the original directive to stay where it is, and I want a clone to land where I drop it. I realize there are other ways around this... Was just wondering if someone had a solution or if this was possible without a lot of work